# Handler_read_rnd is too high (more than 2GB)

Tags: mysql, query

I am running an advertising program and there are some SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE queries when showing ads. Sometimes, displaying ads is fast but sometimes it is too slow. At this time, it is slow and Handler_read_rnd and Handler_read_rnd_next is as mentioned below.

```
Handler_read_rnd    2,844.68 M
Handler_read_rnd_next   2,945.63 M
```

How can I speed-up displaying ads (decreasing Handler_read_rnd and Handler_read_rnd_next)

PS: Currently there are 7,068,528 rows on the advertising program's database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better start looking at your queries and indexes. Make sure you have proper indexes setup and check your queries for large joins, which both can make those counters go up.

There are about a bazilion guides for how to optimize MySQL out on the net. One place to start is [here](http://www.interworx.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-377.html). Or you can have a look at the [MySQLPerformance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/).